Severe UI Lag After Upgrading React Native from 0.63.0 to 0.74.3 When Switching Screens
I recently upgraded my React Native project from version 0.63.0 to 0.74.3, and I’ve started noticing significant lag and slow transitions when switching between screens. This lag wasn’t present before the upgrade. The app used to run smoothly on 0.63.0, but now there’s a noticeable delay whenever I navigate from one screen to another.
Here is a video that demonstrates the lag issue (not my app, but same kind of lag):
https://www.loom.com/share/2b73dae94d324b999d7ed31832565779
Here's what I've tried:

Checked Profiler: There doesn’t seem to be any specific component causing the lag, but it’s apparent when switching screens.
Disabled Hermes: I tried disabling Hermes, thinking it might help, but there was no change.
Profiled Performance: I used React Profiler, and it shows the rendering times for components, but nothing points to a major issue.

As the app is quite large, I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve a lot of changes.
